# Run function when keyboard event is disable

Tags: javascript, events, keyboard, setinterval

I want to run the top set Interval whenever I removed my finger from space but when I use key up event it only run that function one time and I Dont know how to use if/else when I have add Event Listener

```
setInterval(function (e) {
  r--;
}, 10);

document.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
  console.log(r);
  if (e.keyCode === 32) {
    setInterval(function (e) {
      r++;
      if (r > 240) {
        r = 200;
      }
    }, 100);
  }
});
```

Comment: It would help to know more about what you are trying to accomplish

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to do the function for x amount of times, when space is pressed down. If so you might wanne look at the code below. This will do a function for 100 times.

```
var isDoingStuff = false;
var r = 0;

function repeat(func, times) {
    func();
    times && --times && repeat(func, times);
}

function yourFunction(){
    r++;
    if(r > 240){
        r = 200;
    }
}

function onKeyDown(e){
    if (!isDoingStuff && e.keyCode === 32) {
      isDoingStuff = true;
      console.log(r);
      repeat(yourFunction, 100);
      isDoingStuff = false;
    }
}
document.addEventListener("keydown", onKeyDown);
```